# GMaps "mouseout" event not firing when hovering over marker

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have an eventlistener listening for the "mouseout" event on my google maps object.
This works great in most cases, as in it fires when the cursor leaves the bounds of the map.

But if there is a marker at the edge of the map where the cursor leaves it, then it doesn't fire.
See this image for illustration:

[image]

Does anybody know a way to get around this?

Comment: You can set marker event listener for `mouseover` and trigger event `mouseout` for the map object.

Comment: Can you provide a demo? for me mouseout fires also when I leave the map via a marker(or any other kind of overlay). Which browser do you use?

Comment: @AntoJurković Unfortunately that doesn't work for my case as I can't have this event fire every time I hit a marker.

Comment: @Dr.Molle I can't really provide a demo as it is a very complex application which is difficult to strip down and am not allowed to share.
The problem occurs for me only in Chrome. In Firefox and IE11 it works fine.

Comment: Downvote due to lack of code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: That's fair @SteveJansen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving it using both the google maps event listener:

```
this.cursorLeavesMapListener = new google.maps.event.addListener(this.mapObject.gObj, "mouseout", function(e){thisStageMachine.cursorLeftMap()});
```

And this class here:

```
(function(window)
{
    function cursorState(stageMachine)
    {
        this.stageMachine = stageMachine;
        this.state = "out";

        this.currentCheckStateTimer = null;
        var thisCursorState = this;
        this.stageMachine.mapObject.mapDOMDiv.addEventListener("mouseover", function(e){ thisCursorState.setInMapState() });
        this.stageMachine.mapObject.mapDOMDiv.addEventListener("mouseout", 
            function(e){ 
                thisCursorState.setOutOfMapState(); 
                window.clearTimeout(thisCursorState.currentCheckStateTimer);
                thisCursorState.currentCheckStateTimer = window.setTimeout( function(){thisCursorState.checkState()},   100);
            });
    }

    cursorState.prototype.setInMapState = function()
    {
        this.state = "in";
    }

    cursorState.prototype.setOutOfMapState = function()
    {
        this.state = "out";
    }

    cursorState.prototype.checkState = function()
    {
        if(this.state=="out")
        {
            this.stageMachine.cursorLeftMap();
        }
    }

    window.cursorState = cursorState;
}(window));
```

You need this weird construct with the DOMversions of mouseover and mouseout, because they constantly both fire while you're moving your cursor across the map. It probably has something to do with how the tiles are added to the DOM by google maps.
Only the mouseout event however fires, when your mouse leaves the map, so checking for if no new mouseover event has fired (since we last fired mouseout) 100 milliseconds later is what you need to do to make sure we've actually left the map when mouseout is fired.
It is obviously quite hacky, but it works like a charm.

One of the two always fires.

If anybody has a more elegant solution, please share it.